# Making script more dynamic, implementing function or class

Tags: python, python-3.3

Currently my script scrapes 1 url of data, now I would like to scrape 20+ urls so now I am trying to make my code more dynamic, cannot figure out a good solution on how to handle and passing the values of "items/nordfront_items" to a function. Maybe a even better solution would be to use sub-classes? Unfortunately I do not know :)

Would appreciate your help to find a working dynamic solution.

**Old Code, no function**

```
import urllib.request
import lxml.etree as ET  
from pipeline import NordfrontPipeline

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
tree = ET.parse(opener.open('https://nordfront.se/feed'))


items = [{'title': item.find('title').text, 'link': item.find('link').text, 'pubdate': item.find('pubDate').text} for item in tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item")]

pipeline = NordfrontPipeline()

for item in items:
    pipeline.process_item(item, None)
```

**More Dynamic Code, a better solution?**

```
import urllib.request
import lxml.etree as ET  
from pipeline import NordfrontPipeline

nordfront_url = "http://doesntmatter.com/feed"
nordfront_pipe = NordfrontPipeline()
nordfront_items = ?

nordfront_exec = spider(nordfront_url, nordfront_pipe, nordfront_items)

def spider(url, pipe, items)

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    tree = ET.parse(opener.open(url))


    # items = [{'title': item.find('title').text, 'link': item.find('link').text, 'pubdate': item.find('pubDate').text} for        item in tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the items:

```
def spider(url):

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    tree = ET.parse(opener.open(url))

    return [{'title': item.find('title').text, 'link': item.find('link').text, 'pubdate': item.find('pubDate').text} for item in tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item")]
```

Or use them directly:

```
def spider(url, pipe):

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    tree = ET.parse(opener.open(url))

    for item in tree.xpath("/rss/channel/item"):
        pipe.process_item({'title': item.find('title').text, 'link': item.find('link').text, 'pubdate': item.find('pubDate').text}, None)
```

If you want to put all items into just one list, have a look at `list.extend`.